# CGGradient isn't visible (not using interface builder) and UIButtons can't be triggered

Tags: xcode, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uibutton

I have created a view that contains a CGGradient:

```
// Bar ContextRef
CGRect bar = CGRectMake(0, screenHeight-staffAlignment, screenWidth, barWidth);
CGContextRef barContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSaveGState(barContext);
CGContextClipToRect(barContext,bar);    

// Bar GradientRef
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGFloat components[16] = { 1.0,1.0,1.0,0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0, 1.0,1.0,1.0,0.0}; 
CGFloat locations[4] = {0.95,0.85,0.15,0.05};
size_t count = 4;
CGGradientRef gradientRef = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents(colorSpace, components, locations, count);

// Draw Bar
CGPoint startPoint = {0.0,0.0};
CGPoint endPoint = {screenWidth,0.0};
CGContextDrawLinearGradient(barContext, gradientRef, startPoint, endPoint, 0);
CGContextRestoreGState(barContext);
```

This code is called in the drawRect method of the UIView. I then use a UIViewController to access the created view.

```
- (void)loadView {

MainPageView *mpView = [[MainPageView alloc] initWithFrame:[window bounds]];
[self setView:mpView];
[mpView release];
```

}

and displayed on the screen through the appDelegate:

```
mpViewController = [[MainPageViewController alloc] init];   
[window addSubview:[mpViewController view]];

[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

The UIView contains more objects, such as UIButtons, that are visible. I am assuming because they are added as a subview. But I can't work out how to add the CGGradient as a subview? Does it need to be? Is there another reason CGGradient is not visible?

I also don't get the functionality on the UIButtons. I guess that is because of where I have added the UIButtons to the view. Do the buttons need to be added in the UIViewController or the appDelegate to have functionality. Sorry to ask what would seem like simple questions but I am trying to accomplish the programming without the Interface Builder and material on that is scarce. If anyone could point me in the right direction on both these problems I would really appreciate it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functionality on the buttons was lost because the frame was too large but the buttons were still visible because the background was clearColor